# Как превратить ELF файл в питоновский код?

Tags: elf, декомпиляция

У меня есть исполняемый файл формата elf32-i386. Как мне восстановить исходный код?

Comment: А почему вы решили, что из него в принципе возможно восстановить исходный код?

Comment: На python вряд ли возможно, а вот транслировать в ассемблер - пожалуйста!